# Return value of the function when calling another function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

This is what I encounter when trying to do a LeetCode question. I wrote a function to call another recursive function.

This is the way that the output is correct.

```
def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
    right = n
    left = n
    item = ''
    result = []
    self.helper(item, left, right, result)
    return result

def helper(self, item, l, r, result):

    if l==0 and r==0:
        return result.append(item)
    else:
        if l > r:
            return
        else:
            if l > 0:
                self.helper(item+'(', l-1,r, result)
            if r > 0:
                self.helper(item+')', l, r-1, result)
```

However, when I change the first function to this, I will get a empty list [].

```
def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
    right = n
    left = n
    item = ''
    result = []
    return self.helper(item, left, right, result)
```

Cannot quite figure out how the return works in the function, need some help from you guys.

Comment: helper returns None, but modifies result.  You can either make helper return result or return result from generateParenthesis to get a non-empty list returned

Comment: Thank you but I cant understand your meanings. The helper function does return result in the base of the recursive function.

Comment: helper either returns None, or result.append(item), which is None.  By returning helper from generateParenthesis, you are just returning None.

Answer (score 0):

The `helper` function as shown in your source code uses [tail recursion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/what-is-tail-recursion). This is evident from the fact that the `helper` function essentially stores information from the previous recursive call in its argument parameter; hence, the arguments are updated in each recursive call.

But even if this concept is foreign to you, as pointed out by @63677, we can commence from the observation that the `helper` function does not return anything. The `return result.append(item)` might seem like it is returning something, but the `append` function in Python does not return anything (it returns `None`). Therefore, all that `helper` does is to update the argument parameter until it hits the base case.

Calling `self.helper(item, left, right, result)` within the `generateParenthesis` function is going to alter the contents of `result` according to the operations defined in `helper`. The `generateParenthesis` then simply returns that altered `result`.

Your modified code doesn't work since `helper` does not return anything as it is defined (to be more technical, it is tail recursive instead of just recursive). Therefore, the modified code will not work since calling `self.helper` will simply return `None`.